# I am setting up a RETS MLS program using phrets and just wondered what the heck the disable follow location means?

Tags: rets, phrets, mls

I am setting up a RETS MLS program using phrets and just wondered what the heck the disable follow location means?

```
$config = new \PHRETS\Configuration;
$config->setLoginUrl('*****************');
       $config->setUsername('****');
       $config->setPassword('****');
       $config->setUserAgent('****');
       $config->setRetsVersion('1.7.2');
       $config->setOption('disable_follow_location',false);
       $config->setOption('use_post_method',true);
$rets = new \PHRETS\Session($config);
```

Comment: Disable the ability to automatically handle redirects sent by the server. Found here: https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 1):

There was an old feature in PHP called "safe mode" which, when enabled, would complain if something was using cURL in a way where it would automatically follow server-given redirects.  That option was added so that in instances where it wasn't needed (I've never seen it actually used by RETS servers, but it's defined as something RETS clients need to expect), it could be turned off to hide the warning.  It should be safe to ignore nowadays with recent versions of PHP.

I'll likely remove that pretty soon just to clean it up.